# fetching additional information for a particular list item in relay/graphql

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

Using Relay and GraphQL, let's say that I have a schema that returns a viewer, and an embedded list of associated documents. The root query (composed with fragments) would look like something like this:

```
query Root {
  viewer {
    id,
    name,
    groups {
      edges {
        node {
          id,
          name,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow me to display the user, and a list of all of its associated groups.

Now let's say that I want the user to be able to click on that list item, and have it expand to show the comments associated with that particular list item. How should I restructure my query for the relay route such that I can receive those comments? If I add a comments edge to my groups edge, then won't it fetch the comments for all of the groups?

```
query Root {
  viewer {
    id,
    name,
    groups {
      edges {
        node {
          id,
          name,
          comments {
            edges {
              node {
                id,
                content
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or should I alter the route query to find a specific group?

```
query Root {
  group(id: "someid"){
    id,
    name,
    comments {
      edges {
        node {
          id,
          content
        }
      }
    }
  },
  viewer {
    id,
    name,
    groups {
      edges {
        node {
          id,
          name,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My concern is, in particular, using this within the context of `relay`. I.e., how can I efficiently construct a route query that will only fetch the comments for the expanded list item (or items), while still taking advantage of the cached data that already exists, and will be updated when doing mutations? The above example might work for a specific expanded group, but I'm not sure how I could expand multiple groups simultaneously without fetching those fields for *all* of the group items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relay 0.3.2 will support the `@skip` and `@include` directives.

```js
Group = Relay.createContainer(Group, {
  initialVariables: {
    numCommentsToShow: 10,
    showComments: false,
  },
  fragments: {
    group: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Group {
        comments(first: $numCommentsToShow) @include(if: $showComments) {
          edges {
            node {
              content,
              id,
            },
          },
        },
        id,
        name,
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

In your render method, only render comments if `this.props.group.comments` is defined. Invoke `this.props.relay.setVariables({showComments: true})` in the Group component to cause the comments field to be included (and fetched, if necessary).

```js
class Group extends React.Component {
  _handleShowCommentsClick() {
    this.props.relay.setVariables({showComments: true});
  }
  renderComments() {
    return this.props.group.comments
      ? <Comments comments={this.props.group.comments} />
      : <button onClick={this._handleShowCommentsClick}>Show comments</button>;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        {this.renderComments()}
      </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

Comment: For interest's sake: https://github.com/facebook/relay/commit/5330ba5ce697d13febd018f2baac8aedff06bfd6

Comment: Is there a way to fetch additional data for a single item in a list query (_edges_)? **Why?** Im trying to seamlessly transit/scale list item to a single item view. I've tested all kind of strategies but I can't find a way.

Comment: Yes. At the moment you want to show the single item view, you will have come to know the item's ID. At that point, the single item view should roll up to a **node** query at the root. `node(id: $itemID) { ${Component.getFragment('item')} }`. Since the item will already be in the store from the **edges** fetch, no additional network request will be required.

Comment: Yes, this is what I currently have but that's the problem - two different, isolated views and queries and I can't find a way to smootly animate list to single item with this setup. Please look at [this dribbble GIF](https://dribbble.com/shots/2545580-Simple-Profile-Page). **React part is simple**, I'll just calculate the screen size on click and scale the list item to full-screen which pushes other list items out of viewport but how to fetch additional data for that item? I can't use `node()` query as second query for same list component or can I?

Comment: @Solo, can you make a new question on Stack Overflow about this? My answer is too long for a comment.

Comment: Sure, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563484/fetch-additional-data-for-a-single-item-in-a-list-query) my question.